# Remove lines with repeated patterns in VIM

Tags: regex, vim

I have a file each line of which is in format: - x,y, z  - where x, y, z all are numbers. Eg

```
10, 10, 1
10, 11, 2.0
455, 42, 12
```

I want to remove those lines where first two number are equal. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a global command to capture the first number and if the second number is the same it will match the regex.

```
:g/\v(-?\d+(\.\d+)?),\s\1,/d
```

Or without very magic

```
:g/\(-\?\d\+\(\.\d\+\)\?\),\s\1,/d
```

Explanations for the regex.

- `\v` turns on very magic in vim
- `(` start a regex capture/backreference
- `-?` optional minus sign
- `\d+` match any number 1 or more times (which get captured by the backreference)
- `(\.\d+)` optional decimal part
- `)` end regex capture
- `,` match comma
- `\s` match some form of whitespace
- `\1` match the same pattern that was captured in the first backreference (in this case the first number) (ie make sure the numbers are the same
- `,` make sure the number extends to the next comma

`:g` is short for `:global` which for every line that matches the regex executes the ex command after it. The command in this case is `d` which deletes the line.

```
:g/regex/cmd
```

Take a look at `:h :g` and `:h pattern-searches`

Comment: Even the line "11, 14, 4" is deleted.

Comment: @DurgaDatta The regex I have up there doesn't delete "11, 14, 4"

Comment: @DurgaDatta- In what context is `11, 14, 4` also deleted? Are you sure it doesn't match one of the other lines?

Comment: @FDinoff: I think you just need to include a dot in the matching group to account for numbers with decimal points. The sample the OP showed doesn't contain any in the first column, but it does in the third, so I assume it could potentially in the first as well.

Comment: @DurgaDatta: The pattern captures one or more decimal digits with `(\d+)`, and matches a line which then proceeds with a comma, a whitespace character, and then the same set of digits that was initially captured. This last part is called a backreference and is denoted by the `\1` in the pattern. The "global" command, `g`, performs an operation on all lines which match the given expression. In this case, the operation performed is `d`, which means to delete the line. The `\v` at the beginning of the regex just changes the parsing rules a little bit so that you don't have to do as much escaping.

Comment: @DurgaDatta I updated the regex so it should except decimal numbers

Comment: @FDinoff My job is done. But how can we write the same without using "very magic" option, just want to learn.

Comment: @DurgaDatta I added the regex without very magic to the post. Basically you also have to escape all special character which is includes parenthesis, plus, and question mark